# Error with static readonly Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, readonly, public

I have error compiling those line of code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace test
{
    public class testing
    { 
        public static readonly string IN_TABLE_KEY = "IN";
        public static readonly string OUT_TABLE_KEY = "OUT";
        public static readonly string TODAY_TABLE_KEY = "TODAY";
        public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> TEST =
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { IN_TABLE_KEY, "TEST1"},
                { OUT_TABLE_KEY, "TEST2"},
                { TODAY_TABLE_KEY, "TEST3"}
            };
    }
}
```

I really don't understand, this code just won't compile, I don't know if this error is about the syntax or elsewhere in the code.

here the syntax error I got:

> ; expected
>   Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>   A namespace does not directly contain members such as field or methods
>   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Thank you.

Comment: You can't have public local variables. That is declare public local variable in method code...

Comment: sounds like you have bracing issue somewhere above. This code looks fine to me.

Comment: Paste your full file code please.

Comment: Looks to me like you are using an old version of the C# compiler, before collection initializers got added to the language.

Comment: The error message already tells you quite exactly what is wrong here.

Comment: I just tried and it compiling well. Which fw are you using?

Comment: Please paste the entire file.

Comment: sing System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace test
{
    public class testing
    {
public static readonly string IN_TABLE_KEY = "IN";
public static readonly string OUT_TABLE_KEY = "OUT";
public static readonly string TODAY_TABLE_KEY = "TODAY";
public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> TEST = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { IN_TABLE_KEY, "TEST1"},
        { OUT_TABLE_KEY, "TEST2"},
        { TODAY_TABLE_KEY, "TEST3"}
    };
}
}

Comment: A vital piece of information we're missing so far: What framework version are you using? .NET 2? .NET 1.1? .NET 3.5?

Comment: .net version: v4.0.30319

Comment: Judging by the number you've posted, it may be the version that you've installed on the system. Not necesarily the version used in your project. Post the version you've chosen in `Build options`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are placing your declarations outside of your class declaration.

Try this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public class MyClass
   {
      public static readonly string IN_TABLE_KEY = "IN";
      public static readonly string OUT_TABLE_KEY = "OUT";
      public static readonly string TODAY_TABLE_KEY = "TODAY";
      public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> TEST = 
          new Dictionary<string, string>()
             {
                { IN_TABLE_KEY, "TEST1" },
                { OUT_TABLE_KEY, "TEST2" },
                { TODAY_TABLE_KEY, "TEST3" }
             };
   }
}
```

Comment: In the question. It's more likely to be a framework confusion - OP using a framework version of .NET that doesn't support array initialization.

Comment: Hm, could be...that would be .NET 1.1 I guess. But would that really trigger that error message?

Comment: Not sure. I don't have a Studio that old available. =)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, it looks like you forgot to place this inside a class, or forgot namespace declaration.

You can't have global dictionaries in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare it inside the class and not in any method as i have shown in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: Uhm. There's no need for an image, really. =)